# How to pattern match and replace "/bin/sh" to "/bin/bash"

Tags: perl

The pattern match syntax in Perl is as follows...

```
$ctr01 += s/bin/bash/gi;
```

This would replace bin with bash. But if there is a forward slash in the string I want to replace, how would I write it?

How can i replace "/bin/sh" to "/bin/bash", because the forward slash messes with my syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a different regex separator, such as `#`, or nearly anything you choose:  ([This tutorial shows some additional examples with the `m` operator; you can use this with `s` also](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/regex.shtml).)

```
$ctr01 =~ s#/bin/sh#/bin/bash#gi;
```

Alternately, you can escape the slashes:

```
$ctr01 =~ s/\/bin\/sh/\/bin\/bash/gi;
```

Comment: Stackoverflow's syntax highlighter isn't the only one that has problems with `#` symbols (it's ignorant of the whitespace rule for comments). For legibility you might try writing `s[/bin/sh][/bin/bash]gi` instead :)

Comment: I didn't know you could use any characters. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You "escape" a forward slash with a backslash - or you change the separator (the first character after the `s` doesn't have to be a `/`, it could be anything you choose).

Answer (score 0):

Since what you want to replace is at the end of a path and string, you can just use `$` to anchor it for the replacement, w/o worrying about the slashes:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ctr01 = '/bin/sh';
$ctr01 =~ s/sh$/bash/;
print $ctr01;
```

Output:

```
/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ctr01 += s/bin/bash/gi;
```

> This would replace bin with bash.

No, actually it would give you a warning

```
Argument "/bash/bash" isn't numeric in addition (+)
```

And return `1` (the return value of the substitution). The operator you are using is an [assignment operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators) `+=`, which is shorthand for incrementing the left hand argument by the right hand, e.g. `$foo += $bar` is shorthand for `$foo = $foo + $bar`. What you want is `=~`, which is the [binding operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators).

Also, replacing "bin" with "bash" is not what you want. You want to replace "sh" with "bash".

Overcoming the delimiters for the substitution operator is easy, because you can use whatever punctuation character you like. You will want to be sure to *only* replace what you want to replace, though:

```
$crt01 =~ s#/bin/sh#/bin/bash#g
```

You probably don't want the `/i` modifier, because the path is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

declare a scalar variable for the search pattern and the replace pattern.

```
$search="/bin/sh";
$replace="/bin/bash";

if (/$search/gi) {
  s/$search/$replace/gi;
}
```